# XML + DOM + replace text in element

Tags: xml, vb.net, dom

For the following XML:

```
<NET ID="10.10.10.10, 255.255.255.0" />
```

I need to replace the text 10.10.10.10, 255.255.255.0

with 192.9.1.1, 255.0.0.0 by VB + DOM script

so the final line in the XML should be

```
<NET ID="192.9.1.1, 255.0.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is related to your previous question. You can do it like this:

```
objRoot.selectSingleNode("./names/NET1").attributes.getNamedItem("ID").text = "192.9.1.1, 255.0.0.0"
```

Comment: THX allot you have great answer , the short way to replace attr
yael

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
document.getElementById("10.10.10.10, 255.255.255.0").setAttribute("id","192.9.1.1, 255.0.0.0");
```

Comment: is the sytax of your answer fit for VB script?
yael

Comment: well, it is javascript (which you could create using VB)

Comment: I believe the OP was talking about an XML DOM in an application, not an HTML DOM in a browser.